# How to run portions of program separately without separating into cells in Jupyter Notebook (Python)

Tags: python, widget, jupyter

I have a program that I want to execute portions of separately without having to separate them into cells.
I have tried using a Python widget, which upon clicking, will run the portions of the program within the function (see code below). I have found this method to be unreliable and thus I do not see that this could be used in a more sophisticated program.
Is there a way that one can run portions of code within the same cell without having to separate each portion into separate cells?

```
### Read from data file
#Event  track  Qcharge  E0start  X0  Y0  THETA0  PHI0  Xfit  Yfit  Thetafit  Phifit  Chi2norm 
# sort of based on https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila-material/issues/18
itest=0
while itest < 10:
    itest=itest+1

    output = widgets.Output()

    @output.capture(clear_output=False,wait=True) # based on https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1846 and https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html
    def sayHello(b):

        print(' zreac',zreac)
        print(' event',event)
        print(' Energy',Ekin)
        print(' thetareact',thetareac)
        #ntrack= len(zreac)
        #print(' number of tracks', ntrack)
        #search associated tracks and get the energies
        event_combined =  []
        event_old=-1
        nevents = 0
        ntrack = 0
        #print(' number of tracks', ntrack)

        for j in range(len(zreac)):
            print(' j ',j)
            event_new = event[j]
            if event_new == event_old :
                    ntrack = ntrack + 1
                    Ekin2 = Ekin[j]
                    print(' event ntrack E1 E2', event_new,ntrack,Ekin1,Ekin2)
                    theta2 = thetareac[j]
            else: 
                event_old= event[j]
                Ekin1 = Ekin[j]
                theta1 = thetareac[j]
                ntrack = 1
        print(' event tracks ',j)

        with open('X17_data_result.txt','a') as X17_dat:
                X17_dat.write('Event\tntrack\tE1\tE2\tTheta1\tTheta2\tphi1\tphi2\trelatifangle\n')

    # combining variables from 2 tracks (3 tracks not treated)
        for j in range(len(zreac)):
            print(' j ',j)
            event_new = event[j]
            if event_new == event_old :
                ntrack = ntrack + 1
                Ekin2 = Ekin[j]
                theta2 = thetareac[j]*0.017433
                phi2= phireac[j]*0.017433
                print(' event ntrack E1 E2 T1 T2 ', event_new,ntrack,Ekin1,Ekin2)
                #calculation between the 2 vectors (note normalization is =1 of the vectors)
                vectorproduct = (np.sin(theta1)*np.sin(theta2)*np.cos(phi1)*np.cos(phi2)+
                                np.sin(theta1)*np.sin(theta2)*np.sin(phi1)*np.sin(phi2)+
                                np.cos(theta1)*np.cos(theta2) )
                relatifangle = np.arccos(vectorproduct)/0.017433
                print(' event ntrack E1 E2 T1 T2 ', event_new,ntrack,Ekin1,Ekin2,relatifangle)        
                with open('X17_data_result.txt','a') as X17_dat:
                    X17_dat.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(event_new, ntrack,Ekin1,Ekin2,\
                        theta1,theta2,phi1,phi2,relatifangle ))

            else: 
                event_old= event[j]
                Ekin1 = Ekin[j]
                theta1 = thetareac[j]*0.017433
                phi1= phireac[j]*0.017433
                ntrack = 1
        print(' number of event tracks read ',j) 

        print("You have pushed the button, congratulations I guess.")

    run_button = widgets.Button(
        description = 'continue now'
    )
    print("Hello, please push the continue button")
    run_button.on_click(sayHello)
    display(run_button)
    output

    output1 = widgets.Output()
    #@output1.capture(clear_output=False,wait=True) # based on https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1846 and https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html
    def sayHello1(b):

        print(' zreac',zreac)
        print(' event',event)
        print(' Energy',Ekin)
        print(' thetareact',thetareac)
        #ntrack= len(zreac)
        #print(' number of tracks', ntrack)
        #search associated tracks and get the energies
        event_combined =  []
        event_old=-1
        nevents = 0
        ntrack = 0
        #print(' number of tracks', ntrack)

        for j in range(len(zreac)):
            print(' j ',j)
            event_new = event[j]
            if event_new == event_old :
                    ntrack = ntrack + 1
                    Ekin2 = Ekin[j]
                    print(' event ntrack E1 E2', event_new,ntrack,Ekin1,Ekin2)
                    theta2 = thetareac[j]
            else: 
                event_old= event[j]
                Ekin1 = Ekin[j]
                theta1 = thetareac[j]
                ntrack = 1
        print(' event tracks ',j)

        with open('X17_data_result.txt','a') as X17_dat:
                X17_dat.write('Event\tntrack\tE1\tE2\tTheta1\tTheta2\tphi1\tphi2\trelatifangle\n')

    # combining variables from 2 tracks (3 tracks not treated)
        for j in range(len(zreac)):
            print(' j ',j)
            event_new = event[j]
            if event_new == event_old :
                ntrack = ntrack + 1
                Ekin2 = Ekin[j]
                theta2 = thetareac[j]*0.017433
                phi2= phireac[j]*0.017433
                print(' event ntrack E1 E2 T1 T2 ', event_new,ntrack,Ekin1,Ekin2)
                #calculation between the 2 vectors (note normalization is =1 of the vectors)
                vectorproduct = (np.sin(theta1)*np.sin(theta2)*np.cos(phi1)*np.cos(phi2)+
                                np.sin(theta1)*np.sin(theta2)*np.sin(phi1)*np.sin(phi2)+
                                np.cos(theta1)*np.cos(theta2) )
                relatifangle = np.arccos(vectorproduct)/0.017433
                print(' event ntrack E1 E2 T1 T2 ', event_new,ntrack,Ekin1,Ekin2,relatifangle)        
                with open('X17_data_result.txt','a') as X17_dat:
                    X17_dat.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(event_new, ntrack,Ekin1,Ekin2,\
                        theta1,theta2,phi1,phi2,relatifangle ))

            else: 
                event_old= event[j]
                Ekin1 = Ekin[j]
                theta1 = thetareac[j]*0.017433
                phi1= phireac[j]*0.017433
                ntrack = 1
        print(' number of event tracks read ',j) 

        print("You have pushed the button, congratulations I guess.")

    run_button1 = widgets.Button(
        description = 'continue now'
    )
    print("Hello, please push the continue button")
    run_button1.on_click(sayHello1)
    display(run_button1)
    output1
```

What I was hoping this program would do: Execute program within `sayHello()` function upon clicking first widget without executing everything after line containing the variable `output`. Code (contained within function `sayHello1()`) after line containing variable `output` should only be executed upon clicking the 2nd widget.